# Is there any way to use some "shortcut" for longer command lines?

Tags: command-line, command, conemu

I am using the same, longer command line with some arguments every day and it would be nice, if there were some possibility to make some shortcut for it. Is there any?

Comment: What command line exactly are you using?

Comment: It is our internal command line with argument which allow to see error logs, doskey works for me, but I want ConEmu to remember it all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn aliases. Of course they depends of shell you're using. Doskey for cmd, alias for powershell or tcc, and so on.

Also. ConEmu has GuiMacro feature. You may set up user hotkeys with `print` function.

Comment: I followed this -> http://superuser.com/questions/556248/creating-alias-in-conemu. But It does not recognized it in my created tasks with more panes and I don't know what I did wrongly.

Comment: Without clearly described problem nobody can help you

Comment: I have created "Task" (as it is called in Settings -> Tasks) in Conemu with multiple consoles, so I have one window which is split into more terminals. I followed your advance in link mentioned above. I created aliases.cmd as you described and set **cmd /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\aliases.cmd"** into Settings->Startup->Command line. Everything would work fine, but when I open my "Task" with more terminals in one window, it did not recognize my created alias. I tried to put cmd /k "%ConEmuBaseDir%\aliases.cmd" into terminal manually, and it works, but after new startup, it does not recognize again.

Comment: You've created Task. You are running Task. Why do you think that "Startup command line" matters? Add your batch into Task contents of course.

Comment: I added it but it did not work, but I set it wrongly. Now it works like I wanted to, thank you.